# Disable HAXM (HAX kernal Module)

Tags: android, android-studio

My processor(Intel Core 2 Duo E4500) **does not support virtualization** and i think HAXM is also optional, How can i **disable the use of HAXM** from android studio to run the emulator for debugging ?

Thanks for any comment !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio did not use HAXM, Android Emulator X64 system image (from android SDK) use HAXM

my processor is AMD and i can use Android Studio without problem and without disable anything

Comment: Ok sorry for miss-communication !
But i want to use emulator, can you suggest how i can use emulator on my system ?

Comment: just use Genymotion, ARM emulator so slow because it use different processor architecture, and intel x64 emulator can only used in intel processor

Comment: My friend ! there is limitation that i have only 2 gb ram .

Comment: it hard to develop android with only 2GB ram my friend, you need to upgrade your PC. Its hard to think other option

Comment: ya sure i will ! but i am trying if it is possible with google's emulator.

Comment: google emulator use ARM processor architecture because majority android phone use ARM processor, beside PC use x86/x64 processor architecture, because of that difference architecture android emulator from Android SDK is so slow even with my PC (AMD PhenomII x4 955 & 10GB ram)

Right now Genymotion is best android emulator you can get

Comment: thank you friend ! i will finally go with ARM processor because of my current limitation, once i will update my system then i will use HAXM.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to use an emulator, have you tried using an external one? I'd recommend you Genymotion, it works really great and fast, i think it will work fine in your processor, and you don't need HAXM.

Comment: Dear Vitor ! 
Thanks for your response !

but the minimum requirement for ""Genymotion"" is 8 gb of RAM, but i have only 2 gb, thats why i am going to google's emulators

Comment: Where did you see it was 8 gb RAM the minimum? See in this link the requirements: [link](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#requirements). I actually use Genymotion in a 2GB RAM PC also.

Comment: Sorry it was some other link i dont remember but now i preferebly going for upgrad my pc with following config:

Motherboard: Asus H97 Pro         
Processor: intel 4th generation i5                 
Ram: Corsair Vengeance Pro Series 38GB) DDR3 DRAM 2800MHz     
SSD: Samsung EVO 850 120Gb.        

Please Suggests !